# Opening multiple files with a single command

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, command-line-tool

I noticed I can for example do below in git bash to open three files in visual studio code simultaneously

```
$ code space_age.go && code cases_test.go && code space_age_test.go
```

Is there syntax available such that I don't have to type "code" three times?

Comment: Did you try running `code file1.go file2.go`?

Comment: Whoops, that worked, thx!